# How do I check the running kernel version?

Tags: kernel, version, system-information

While troubleshooting a problem with my ethernet card, I've found that the driver I'm currently using may have some issues with old kernel versions. What command can I use to check the kernel version I am currently running ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can execute:

```
uname -r
```

It will display something like

```
3.13.0-62-generic
```

---

Found on https://askubuntu.com/questions/359574/how-do-i-find-out-the-kernel-version-i-am-running (**view that QA to learn other commands you could use**)

Answer (score 3):

For **Ubuntu**

enter the command

```
# uname -r
```

will Print the kernel name

```
# uname -a
```

Will Print all Information

or else we can check with **cat /proc/version**

For **Redhat and centos**

```
# cat /etc/redhat-release

# lsb_release –a
```

Answer (score 1):

```
dmesg | grep Linux
```

This command reads boot logs as it startup.

Output:

> [    0.000000] Linux version 4.9.0-8-amd64
>   (debian-kernel@lists.debian.org) (gcc version 6.3.0 20170516 (Debian
>   6.3.0-18+deb9u1) ) #1 SMP Debian 4.9.110-3+deb9u4 (2018-08-21)

Answer (score 0):

`uname -r` for exact version of the kernel or `uname -a` for information in the kernel AND information about your distro.

Answer (score 0):

```
uname -rv
```

gives both, revision and version. This works on all UNIX platforms since ~1982, except for AIX (Alien UNIX ;-) because IBM implemented AIX after reading the man pages and confused -r with -v and vice versa ;-)

Answer (score 0):

**/etc/redhat-release** gives only current version

> Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.2 (Maipo)

To get kernel details in Redhat use /proc/version.

**cat /proc/version**

> Linux version 3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64
>   (mockbuild@x86-034.build.eng.bos.redhat.com) (gcc version 4.8.3
>   20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-9) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Thu Oct 29 17:29:29 EDT 2015

**OR**

**uname -a**

> Linux  3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Oct 29 17:29:29 EDT
>   2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 0):

> #### How do I check the running kernel version?

What you want is known as the kernel *release*.
Here is how I output the *name*, *release*, and *version*
of the kernel
when running Ubuntu 22.04 (jammy) on WSL2 :
<sup>1</sup>

```
$ uname --kernel-name              # or uname -s
Linux
$ uname --kernel-release           # or uname -r
5.10.16.3-microsoft-standard-WSL2
$ uname --kernel-version           # or uname -v
#1 SMP Fri Apr 2 22:23:49 UTC 2021
```

If you prefer to get it all in one go :

```
$ uname --all                      # or uname -a
Linux hp 5.10.16.3-microsoft-standard-WSL2 #1 SMP Fri Apr 2 22:23:49 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

### Reference

- [`uname(1)` | Linux and UNIX Man Pages](https://www.unix.com/man-page/linux/1/uname/)

---

<sup>1</sup>
It so happens that the output is identical when running
Debian 11 (bullseye) on WSL2.