# Will Upgrading Debian Kernel Change output of lsb_release?

Tags: debian, kernel, upgrade, backports

I started with a Debian Jessie distribution and have upgraded it from a 3.X kernel to 4.19 now. There are still things that are not fully working (broken packages etc). As I am going through cleanup I have found that currently running `lsb_release -a` gets me:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 8.11 (jessie)
Release:        8.11
Codename:       jessie
```

Would a proper Debian Kernel upgrade change the output of lsb_release?

Comment: If you want the *kernel* release: [`uname -r`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/726284).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`lsb_release`](https://refspecs.linuxbase.org/LSB_3.1.1/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/lsbrelease.html) doesn’t output the kernel version, so no, upgrading the kernel won’t change its output.